# Why I cannot see the grails application after created in the NetBeans IDE 8.0.2

Tags: grails, netbeans-8

I already made set up for Grails. But After I created grails application in the NetBeans, It didn't display grails application under project window.
I use NetBeans IDE 8.0.2, Grails 3.0.8 and JVM 1.8.0_45.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not supported.

You can try the nightly builds because the developers have added support for those builds.

You can check them here: http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/

Comment: Thanks. Can I use older Grails version?

Comment: Yes the 2.3 / 2.2 grails. Please mark as answered. Thanks